# Удаление строк из БД MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Пишу на PHP. В общем у меня данные из БД помещаются в массив и потом циклом по порядочку выводятся. Надо сделать ссылку, чтобы удалить определенную строку. Только вот я вообще понятия не имею, как будут выглядеть ссылки, как сделать программу и т.д. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();
require "db.inc.php";
require "lib.inc.php";

$id = $_GET["id"];
pagedel($id);
header ("location: index.php");

function pagedel($id){    // функция удаления страниц
    $sql = "DELETE FROM pages WHERE id=$id";
    mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

а вот так будет выглядеть ссылка на само удаление

```
<a href="delete-form-page.php?id=<?=$items["id"]?>">Удалить </a>`
```

Comment: @kira - чтобы оформить блок кода - выдилите код и нажмите кнопочку **101010**. Кавычки используются для оформления инлайнового кода (кода в тексте)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM `tablename` WHERE `id` = '{id}';
```